# 30 mins Idleness, watermark event timer does not trigger

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My use case is to fire an event timer if the 2nd event did not come within 30 mins. Hence, I'll have 30 mins idless in between of the 2 events. My event timer triggers only if I send consequent events every atleast 1 sec, but does NOT if in between it's 30 mins gap, the onTimer never triggers. (Using PeriodicWatermarkAssigner)

How can I trigger if 30 mins gap is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Event time timers are triggered by watermarks, which are only created from events. So if there are no events, there are no watermarks, and the timer will never fire. You'll need to use a processing time timer if the sources are completely idle.